# Rx.Observable.create is not invoking the passed function with jest

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, jestjs

While testing with jest, this code did not print a `console.log`:

```
const observe = Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
  console.log('InnerFunction', observer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, I didn't call `.subscribe` on the `observe` object, so the inner function was never triggered